# RTC 4.0.6 View Component Scope Change History

Tags: version-control, rtc, rational-team-concert

My team has recently had an issue where the scope on a component was changed to "Team Private". No person on my team should have the authority to perform this change except myself as the project manager. I'm trying to find a way to view the history of a component to determine who made the change so I can prevent this from happening in the future.

I've tried to find a component history (not the component change set history) in the RTC client and in the browser interface but haven't had any luck. I have direct access to the RTC CCM database on the AIX DB2 server and I can find the row for this component on the SCM.COMPONENT table but the ITEM_ID is in a weird format and I'm not able to correlate it's value with anything on any of the other CCM tables. I tried creating a ER diagram by reverse engineering the SCM via IBM Data Studio but the diagram doesn't display any of the relationship information for the tables (I can do this on a z/OS DB2 database and it works properly so I know the process is correct) so I'm in the dark when it comes to the table relations with the SCM tables.

What are my options for viewing the change history of a component? Is it even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest source of (temporary) information that *might* have recorded the change is the event stream of the project.

See for instance "[Is there RTC component rename history?](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/126173/is-there-rtc-component-rename-history)":

> Yes, there is.
>   It is captured in the event log for the project area.
>   Open the feed associated with the project area and you'll see a record of who renamed it, when and 
>   the before/after the rename operation.
>
> FYI, the event log doesn't last forever.
>   It will eventually be purged. I believe it only shows you the last few hundred events. If there's a lot of activity, the record won't last long.
>
> The events come from the feed management used in all Jazz based products and it doesn't have a way to set the limit.

You can check if that applies to scope changes.

There is an enhancement request to have those logs kept around for a longer or customizable period of time: [Enhancement 279808](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=279808)... don't hold your breath though.

Comment: VonC, thank you very much for this answer. I searched on stackoverflow but I guess I didn't search on the correct keywords. I checked the event log and it does show when owner is changed 

"**** set component '**** Component' owner to process area '**** Team Area'"

Unfortunately it shows when I fixed the owner this morning, but it doesn't show when it was initially changed even though it goes all the way back to mid-October. Oh well, I guess this will be one of those unexplainable things that happens in programming.

Thanks again for your help.